# CodeIgniter - How to show error message from do_upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to show the success message of a content insert on a redirect link.here is my code of controller:-

```
public function do_upload($field) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $config['max_width'] = '3000';
        $config['max_height'] = '3000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            return $error;
        } else {

            $updata =$this->upload->data();
            $data = $updata['raw_name'].$updata['file_ext'];
            return $data;
        }


     }


public function index() {

 $this->load->model('blog');

        if(isset($_POST['post']) && (!empty($_POST['post']) || strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) ){
        if(strlen($_FILES['inputUpProfile']['name']) > 0) 
        {
        $pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');
        print_r($pic);
        if ($this->input->post('post') == ''){$type="image";} else {$type="image-with-text";}
        }

        else {$pic = ""; $type = "text"; }

            $result = $this->blog->addPost($_SESSION['user_id'], $type  , $this->input->post('post'),$pic);
        }
$this->template->build('home_view',$this->data);
}
```

when upload image big than 3000 its was show me this message

```
Array ( [error] =>

The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
)
```

how can i read this error in my view ??

================================================

Update :-

the error messagelike this:-

```
Array ( [error] =>

The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
)
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Line Number: 552
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\AppServ\www\cc\ccc\application\controllers\home.php:83)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 442
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `events` (`ev_user_id`, `ev_type`, `ev_text`, `ev_pic`, `ev_date`) VALUES (445, 'image', '', Array, '2013-10-03 23:51:47')

Filename: E:\AppServ\www\cc\ccc\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 14):

if you got error like

```
Array ( [error] =>
   The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
)
```

in the controller you can do like

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$error['error']);
    redirect('your_function_which_loads_the_view','refresh');
}
```

and in the view page do something like

```
if($this->session->flashdata('error')){echo $this->session->flashdata('error');}
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: hello sir, what if multiple images are getting uploded and some non image type file is also added to the files. CI actually gives error, work fine but some files are getting uploded in this process. what should i do to check all file at first in CI?

Comment: $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$this->upload->display_errors()); would be just fine as well, but remember the function by default encapsulates the text with <p>..</p>, so display_errors( '', '' ) might be useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

just display the error in your view, here the steps:
first load session library, do it at folder config, file aoutoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

in the controller as you have, change this piece of code for this

```
  if (!$this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors() );
    redirect( base_url( 'your view' ) );
  }
```

in your view file...

```
    <?php
    if ( $this->session->flashdata( 'error_msg' ) ) {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('error_msg');
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pic = $this->do_upload('inputUpProfile');
$this->data['upload_error'] = $pic['error'];
```

Then in the view:

```
echo $upload_error;
```

Comment: You have 3 errors there 2 of which are in your model which you did not provide the code for. The first error tells you exactly what is wrong: the type of file is not allowed. This is a configuration which can be set. Please read the user guide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/